# error importing opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv

I installed opencv using these commands on my mac:

```
$ wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.3/OpenCV-2.4.3.tar.bz2
$ tar xjvf OpenCV-2.4.3.tar.bz2
$ cd OpenCV-2.4.3
$ mkdir build; cd build
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=i386 -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-m32 -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-m32 ..
$ make -j4
$ sudo make install
```

then I tried to use it by importing it but got the error below:

```
~/opencv-2.4.4/build $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 28 2013, 14:31:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

**Updates**

While compiling OpenCV I noticed that its picking up python libraries from a previous version (one installed by apple):

```
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version "2.7.2", but required is exact version "2.7.3" (found /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib)

--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/local/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.3)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (ver 2.7.2)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.7.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: OK, you clearly have some third-party Python 2.7 in addition to Apple's Python 2.7. Most likely, what happened is that OpenCV built for Apple's, and you're running it with another. Without knowing what you installed, and exactly how and why and what your PATH looks like in different scenarios and so on, it's very hard to say exactly what, but I'm guessing `python` means the third-party for you, but inside `sudo` it means the Apple one.

Comment: Wait… why did you explicitly ask OpenCV to build for i386? If you want to build a 32-bit OpenCV, you have to use it with a 32-bit Python. Apple's Python, and most others, are universal (32-/64-bit) so it's just a matter of starting them differently, while if you have a 64-bit-only Python you may have to rebuild… but either way, I have to wonder why you want 32-bit.

Comment: I installed python by `brew install python` and its version 2.7.3. from the error it looks like its complaining about architecture. I am on 64 however, I gave tags for 32 while compiling opencv. perhaps that is an issue. I am compiling and installing opencv again after removing those tags. Will update

Comment: we both spotted same thing :). yeah, i don't want 32 bit. I took that command from the web somewhere and stupidly copy pasted it...

Comment: Well, you probably have _both_ problems. Watch OpenCV as it compiles and see which Python it's linking against, and I'll bet you it's Apple's. (If you see anything about version 2.7.2, or a path in `/System`, or in `/usr/lib` instead of `/usr/local/lib`… that's Apple's Python.) So, you will get past this problem only to crash a little bit later.

Comment: >_< this time i compiled with `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON ..` but again I'm getting same error. Let me watch what you suggested and i'll post back. thanks

Comment: Also, is there a reason you didn't just `brew install opencv`? And, if there is… do you actually need Homebrew's Python? There are some good reasons (you need 2.7.3 not 2.7.2; you need to build standalone packages with `py2app`; you need the system `site-packages` to be world-writable for some reason; etc.), but if you don't have one, life is much easier with only one Python 2.7 on your path.

Comment: `brew install opencv` would have been great but it doesn't work. I opened an issue for it as well: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/18801

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that the problem is "mach-o, but wrong architecture". That generally means that you're trying to load a 32-bit library in a 64-bit app, or vice-versa (or similarly, for Intel vs. PowerPC).

Whichever Python you've installed, it's likely that you got a universal build that can run as either a 32-bit app or a 64-bit app, but by default it runs as 64-bit. But you're explicitly building OpenCV for 32-bit:

```
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=i386 -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-m32 -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-m32 ..
```

If that was a mistake, just rebuild and don't do that.

If you want it to be 32-bit, you can start a Universal python in 32-bit mode, or install a 32-bit Python.

---

Meanwhile, you're trying to run this with a Homebrew-installed Python 2.7.3, but there's a good chance that you're building it against Apple's pre-installed 2.7.2 (or, worse, partially building it one way, partially another).

First, the usual way people add Homebrew to their PATH doesn't affect any commands run with `sudo`, so if `sudo make install` does anything to find your Python, it will likely find a different one than `cmake` and `make` did.

Second, both Apple's Python and Homebrew's think they own `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` (and also think they have exclusive rights to install tools/scripts like `/usr/local/bin/pip-2.7`), which makes this even more painful.

Comment: What a mess...Any way I can get rid of apple's python completely?

Comment: No, you definitely cannot get rid of Apple's python. You may break the OS, and the next OS update will replace it anyway. Is there a reason you can't get rid of the Homebrew Python?

Comment: no reason. I just wanted to start with the latest version so I went with `brew install python`. Should I just remove it by `brew uninstall python`

Comment: Otherwise, you have to figure out why OpenCV's configure process is picking up Apple's Python, and then you can figure out how to change your configuration or work around it. The problem _may_ just be that OpenCV doesn't understand framework builds, and creating a symlink from your Cellar's Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python to /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.dylib will fix it.

Comment: You may want to just `brew unlink python` so you can restore it later if you change your mind (and, for that matter, you can continue to use it by using an explicit path into the `Cellar`). But yeah, I'd remove it. Many people disagree with me, but see [here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/02/sticking-with-apples-python-27.html) for my reasons. Or just look at the mess you're having and what it'll take to debug it for reasons.

Comment: I unlinked it but still no luck. I wanted to try opencv to try hough transform an image but this is such a mess to try something >_<. I've put all my output in a gist. https://gist.github.com/Omnipresent/5266694 if you could please shed some light on what to do next, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: OK, the new problem is that it's finding something called `/usr/local/bin/python2` (which it detects as Python 1.4?!). Neither Apple nor Homebrew normally installs something with that name. If you don't know where that came from, `ls -l` it to see if it's a symlink to something from Homebrew or something else weird, and `file` it to see if it's a binary or a script, and paste the script somewhere if it's a script. And maybe try to run it and see what it does. Most likely you can just delete it, but let's be safe here…

Comment: this required a lot of changes. But I got it finally working. Here are steps for others: openCV doesn't work with java 1.7 but there is a patch for this: https://github.com/apavlenko/opencv/commit/c66cf08cedde16d60d84d74e01214b419e5919ae this patch was applied today in home-brew https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commit/bb2035c527e86a6a832e49711761ab62ef83065f. Steps for a clean install should be: `brew install python` then export the PATH `export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"` then install openCV `brew install opencv`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, (arm-linux-gcc (uclibc) cross-compilation from debian),

Python was trying to load the right file with dlopen (/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so), but I got "File not found" whereas file exists.

On my board :

```
$ python
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: File not found
```

In fact, the dynamic load was trying to load recursively dependant libraries (of course). However, in my case, libstdc++ was not embed on my board whereas opencv needed it :

Host side:

```
$ arm-linux-readelf -d ./lib/cv2.so 
Dynamic section at offset 0x24197c contains 23 entries:
Tag        Type                         Name/Value
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpython2.7.so.1.0]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.0]*
```

I hope it can help.